# Mvvmcross Location iOS doesn't work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm using mvvmcross location plugin and it's works fine in android. But iOS version doesn't work. When I have installed my app and check Location Service in settings. I setup it to "Always". It's how I start location watcher:

```
 MvxGeoLocation _location;
 IMvxLocationWatcher _locationWatcher = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxLocationWatcher>();
 _locationWatcher.Start(new MvxLocationOptions(), OnLocation, OnError );
```

[image]

When I start my app and click on start location button - nothing is happening.
And then I have checked my location services again:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it. I should add this to my info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message goes here</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message goes here</string>
```